# How to send alert to client when database is updated, like facebook chat

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to send alert to client who is using the website only when saome field gets updated.
i know how to regularly check for database updations with silent ajax calls.
I only want to trigger an ajax call when there is information updated.
In other Words, the mysql server will send an alert to client that some table row is changed so that the client will trigger the ajax call and the info can be retrieved.

Comment: you need to use socket

Comment: Which socket you talk about ? Author's client is browser.

Comment: Should give this a read: http://www.developerfusion.com/article/143158/an-introduction-to-websockets/

Comment: Long polling is always an option too.

Comment: what is long polling?

Answer (score 1):

You can use websockets with PHP. Take a look at [Thruway](https://github.com/voryx/Thruway). Thruway uses WAMP which supports a publish and subscribe message model. You could use the [AutobahnJS](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnJS) JavaScript library on the browser side to subscribe to events published by PHP when it makes database updates.

Disclaimer: I am a project maintainer for Thruway.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do so is the use of realtime technologies such as nodejs, however there is a way around in php (with javascript/jquery). I once develop a chat with php and javascript. All i did is set five seconds interval in javascript to listen to the server for any new message and append it to the chat box.

Comment: Author said that he doesn't want to use this technique: ** i know how to regularly check for database updations with silent ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

If your webserver is node use websockets otherwise the only other way is to long poll (use setInterval) to query the database every 30 seconds or so

Comment: I thought long polling was the notion of waiting for the server to respond to a request? Thus mimicking a kind of 'push'? I may be wrong.

Comment: my question was the server will alert the client.

Comment: If you want the server to alert the client you'll need websockets. Each client can be subscribed to unique event names. The server then broadcasts on these subscriptions to send data to each client.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
function checkUpdate()
{
 jQuery.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "your.php",
   data: "name=currentUser&",   //our any other data you want to check
   success: function(msg){
     if(msg.indexOf('no Updates') !== -1 )
         {
            alert( "You have an update" );
     }
 });
}
```

You can use the above code to call and get response from your.php and will alert when the response doesnt contain "no Updates." I suggest you to do this periodically by this code every 2 minute:

```
window.setInterval("checkUpdate()", 2*60*1000); // our any other period you want
```

Comment: i know this technique, i want the server to alert client browser.

Comment: This answer actually refers to what we call Ajax polling or in some cases ajax long polling. In both methods(Polling & long Polling) you should check for any changes and the server respond to you according to your intervals.

Comment: i know how to check for data in database with synchornous ajax calls, what i need is the server alerting the client automatically without client sending ajax requests again and again and then server responds.